# Can create function in regex tester but not in an app

Tags: javascript, regex

Using the following regex:

```
/\,|[^0-9/.]/g
```

On [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) matches the pattern I'm looking for. However, when I'm calling it in JavaScript in my app:

```
value = value.replace(/\,|[^0-9\/.]/g, '');
```

It doesn't cover the following characters:

```
,./<>?;':"[]{}-_=+
```

Is there something in JavaScript I don't know about that is preventing these characters from being caught?

Comment: Can you post an example string which fails to work?

Comment: This is a function that is being called on an input string, so attempting to enter something like 145< should immediately delete the character <

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue, @Thomas. See [this demo](http://js.do/code/39750). Is the output incorrect? If so, what should be the correct one? Could you update the question with more relevant code? It could be something else that is causing the issue.

Comment: what is your expected input and output? Can you share a sample?

Comment: you want to check only for these characters `,./<>?;':"[]{}-_=+` right?

Comment: Input = 1552kkj<
Out = 1552

Comment: @Braj Yes, those are the only characters I wish to check for

Comment: Look at my post that might help you.

Comment: `"1552kkj<".replace(/\,|[^0-9\/.]/g, '') === "1552"`, so I fail to see what does not work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What I want to keep are all numbers and the** `,` **character**

---

The following will replace everything **except** number characters and the comma character.

```
value = value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '');
```

Comment: Nope, no dice.

Input = 1552kkj< 
Out = 1552

Comment: What I want to keep are all numbers and the , character

Comment: Hi @hwnd, nope, still not doing it. Totally agree with your approach, just not sure why the replacer isn't doing its thing. Its pulling out other characters like !@#$% perfectly.

Comment: Theres more to what you are saying then, show your code and what your trying to do.

Comment: Indeed there was. It was an issue with certain event.keyCodes being grabbed in another loop.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you if your are looking for only those character that is not digit, not letters and not space. It covers all the characters that is mentioned by you.

```
[^((0-9)|(a-z)|(A-Z)|\s)]
```

Demo on [regexr](http://regexr.com/3913e) and [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sQ7vN6)

<sub>**Note:** Remove extra ones from the pattern as per your need.</sub>